# Change elements in webapp from value of variable in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, node.js

I am making a webapp that has to be connected to an Arduino for its inputs so the contents of the webpage change.

I am currently not done yet, so I'm just trying it out with vars I have created and given random numbers. However, I am new to jQuery and cannot get it to work properly. For instance, I have the variable `light = 100` and I want to make an `if` statement that `if light > 100` the website displays the message: `your plant is happy`.

I don't know how to change the value with just the input of a variable, without having to click on any elements or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using Arduino hardware to detect the intensity of light and then use that information to update information on a webpage in real time.

One way to do this is:

1. Define the ranges for the plant state (eg. 'happy'  100+, 'okay'  80 to 100, 'sad' < 80, etc.)
2. Program your Arduino board to send the state to your server (eg: a python flask server) whenever the light intensity moves in and out of the set ranges.
3. Use Server Sent Events (SSE) or WebSockets to update the plant state into browser clients which are connected to your web server.